# How can I verify that the onReceive method of a Broadcast Receiver from a different App is actually called?

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I'm a beginner with Android and I am confronted with the following problem.
I'm trying to call a Broadcast Receiver registered by App A from (a different) App B.
In App A's Broadcast Receiver I have implemented the following `onReceive()` method, for testing purposes:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    //TODO: React to the Intent received.
    System.out.println("onReceive has been called");
}
```

The Boradcast Receiver is called with the following code within App B:

```
Intent explicitIntent = new Intent();
explicitIntent.setComponent(new ComponentName("<A's package name>", "<fully qualified BR class name>"));
sendBroadcast(explicitIntent);
```

When running App B, I expected to see the `onReceive has been called` string appearing on the Android Studio console, but it doesn't.
Is it because the method is in fact not called (for some reason) or because it is naive to expect that App B console can visusalize `System.out.println` messages from App A?
In the second case, is there another simple way to test in Android Studio that the `onReceive()` method from App A is actually called?

Comment: Placing a break point should help.

Comment: Pls show us how do you register your broadcast receiver (is it implicit or explicit) as well as your API level.

Comment: @ror, it is registered in A's manifest, like this <receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"/> and it is called explicitly (the purpose of the effort is in fact to verify if I can call explicitly a BR in a different app). API level is 29.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<del>I do not have your API ver to test with,</del> but your setup will work if you register your receiver a bit differently:

```
<receiver android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"  android:exported="true"/>
```

Comment: yes it works, and I can see System.out output from app A in the app B Android Studio project (by selecting the appropriate package in the Logcat window)